# What all we need to start working with SharePoint Framework

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-server, spfx, modern-experience, spfx-tooling

I am new to SharePoint framework, am not aware which technologies need to be learn to work and develop workflows using spfx.

Any suggestions would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: SharePoint Framework is a technology for extending the user interface in SharePoint and Teams. You cannot develop workflows using SharePoint Framework. This would be done with Power Automate or Logic Apps.

Answer (score 0):

- SPFx is framework-agnostic. You can use any JavaScript framework that you like including, but not limited to, React, Handlebars, Knockout, Angular, and Vue.js.
- The developer toolchain is based on popular open-source client development tools such as NPM, TypeScript, Yeoman, webpack, and gulp.

You can find more information at: [Overview of the SharePoint Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/SharePoint-framework-overview)

You can find detailed information related to tools / softwares used for SPFx at: [Set up your SharePoint Framework development environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/set-up-your-development-environment)

Comment: Hi @Sai, Does this answer your question? If yes, please [accept it as an Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) as it helped you & it will help others with similar question in future to find the correct answer easily.  It also removes this question from "Unanswered questions" list.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend going through this free Microsoft Learn learning path. It will give you a good introduction to the capabilities of the SharePoint Framework and how to implement them.

[Extend Microsoft SharePoint – Associate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/training/paths/m365-sharepoint-associate/)

[image]